# Hibernate JBoss tools installed but it does not show Hibernate perspective

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am using Eclipse JUNO and from the market place I installed Hibernate JBoss tools, it installed in my eclipse (also show JBoss icon in help-->about eclipse) but it does not display Hibernate perspective in my eclipse's perspective. I already restart it after its installation.
I also installed it with other Eclipses but does not help too much.
Please suggest me what should i do to make it correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any specific reason you want to run it on Juno and not use one of the later versions ?

Comment: Because It's hard to install a full portable environment (Eclipse + JDK + ...) for example : you have to find all good link between portable JDK and application and you have every link ok, it's hard to imagine to switch your eclipse version ...